# Keep notification area always show on GNOME 3

Tags: linux, gnome, gentoo, notification-area

I've installed GNOME 3 on my Gentoo Linux, it really awesome and I love it.

But here is a little glitch that I don't get used to: The notification area is hide until I hit "Windows" key or move the mouse cursor to the right-bottom corner.

Since I've some program use the notification to indicate their status (for example, my Chinese input method use this to indicate whether I'm in English mode or Chinese mode. And a program that show the CPU temperature on the notification area).

It becomes a little inconvenient if I've to move the cursor or hit "Windows" key just in order to check those status.

So is it possible to make the notification area always show on the screen? Or is it possible to integrate the notification area to menu bar just like GNOME 2.X or XFCE4?

Besides that, I would like to know is it possible to remove the accessibility on the menu bar top-right corner? I don't need it completely, it just a waste of space for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it could achieve by GNOME Shell Extension and wrote an extension for this purpose.

The extension and instruction of how to use it is on this [blog page](http://bone.twbbs.org.tw/blog/archives/2148) (It has Chinese UI, but this article is written in English so it should be fine, I guess).